# Can I masquerade a kernel uevent?

Tags: linux-kernel, udev, usb-device

**What I think happens**

From my understanding this is what happens when I connect a USB device to my computer:

1. Kernel recognizes that I plugged in a USB device
2. Kernel setups the very low-level things for the new device like drivers etc.
3. Kernel sends a `uevent` to the `udev` daemon.
4. Udev daemon uses the information sent, to populate the appropriate files in `/dev`.

**What I want to do**

I was thinking that maybe I could jump directly to **step 3** by manually sending a uevent to udev. Since the uevent is sent via netlink and [netlink is based on sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink), theoretically this should be possible since I just need to know which socket to write to. Anyone who has any idea if this can work and how?

Comment: `udevadm trigger` may do what you want. An example from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev : `udevadm trigger -v -t subsystems -c remove -s usb -a "idVendor=abcd"
`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks for the link. However I am not sure to use that. I tried the command given and run `udevadm monitor` but nothing seems to happen..

Comment: Why do you want to skip step 2?

Comment: @Nils because I create a virtual device. What I want is udev to think that it's an actual device.

Comment: So blacklisting the driver will not help you here.

Answer (score 2):

### udevadm trigger

#### 1. try it

```
sudo udevadm trigger --verbose --action=remove --property-match='DEVNAME=/dev/sdd'
```

will trigger a `/dev/sdd` remove uevent, content as

```
remove@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sdd
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sdd
SUBSYSTEM=block
MAJOR=8
MINOR=48
DEVNAME=sdd
DEVTYPE=disk
SEQNUM=12589
```

#### 2. `strace` it

see what he dose:

```
sudo strace udevadm trigger --verbose --action=remove --property-match='DEVNAME=/dev/sdd'
...
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 37), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc0596a7000
write(1, "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:"..., 101/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sdd
) = 101
open("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sdd/uevent", O_WRONLY) = 3
write(3, "remove", 6)                   = 6
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

#### 3. summarize

actually, it only does

```
echo 'remove' | sudo tee /sys/block/sdd/uevent
```

this way still depend on sysfs:

- device sysfs must exist
- can't totally custom uevent message body

the sysfs uevent file:

```
cat /sys/block/sdd/uevent
MAJOR=8
MINOR=48
DEVNAME=sdd
DEVTYPE=disk
```

refs:
http://fibrevillage.com/sysadmin/93-udevadm-useage-examples
http://arakilab.media.eng.hokudai.ac.jp/~msylw/2013/07/using-udev-to-trigger-events-in-example/